# Selenium Error Element not interactable Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am new to selenium, trying to automate a webpage form. Using Excel 2016 with VBA and Chrome browser.

The particular page requires login credentials, so unable to share the URL where this error happens.

There are couple of dropdown items, which I am having trouble with. I get Selenium Error, Element not interactable. Below is one such element. Sorry, I am not able to get the complete HTML code here.

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
                                                <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlScopeYear" id="MainContent_ddlScopeYear" class="chosen-select select_styled" style="display: none;">
            <option selected="selected" value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
            <option value="2021">2021</option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="1998">1998</option>
            <option value="1997">1997</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1993">1993</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="1989">1989</option>
            <option value="1988">1988</option>
            <option value="1987">1987</option>
            <option value="1986">1986</option>
            <option value="1985">1985</option>
            <option value="1984">1984</option>
            <option value="1983">1983</option>
            <option value="1982">1982</option>
            <option value="1981">1981</option>
            <option value="1980">1980</option>
            <option value="1979">1979</option>
            <option value="1978">1978</option>
            <option value="1977">1977</option>
            <option value="1976">1976</option>
            <option value="1975">1975</option>
            <option value="1974">1974</option>
            <option value="1973">1973</option>
            <option value="1972">1972</option>
            <option value="1971">1971</option>
            <option value="1970">1970</option>
            <option value="1969">1969</option>
            <option value="1968">1968</option>
            <option value="1967">1967</option>
            <option value="1966">1966</option>
            <option value="1965">1965</option>
            <option value="1964">1964</option>
            <option value="1963">1963</option>
            <option value="1962">1962</option>
            <option value="1961">1961</option>
            <option value="1960">1960</option>
            <option value="1959">1959</option>
            <option value="1958">1958</option>
            <option value="1957">1957</option>
            <option value="1956">1956</option>
            <option value="1955">1955</option>
            <option value="1954">1954</option>
            <option value="1953">1953</option>
            <option value="1952">1952</option>
            <option value="1951">1951</option>
            <option value="1950">1950</option>
            <option value="1949">1949</option>
            <option value="1948">1948</option>
            <option value="1947">1947</option>
            <option value="1946">1946</option>
            <option value="1945">1945</option>
            <option value="1944">1944</option>
            <option value="1943">1943</option>
            <option value="1942">1942</option>
            <option value="1941">1941</option>
            <option value="1940">1940</option>
            <option value="1939">1939</option>
            <option value="1938">1938</option>
            <option value="1937">1937</option>
            <option value="1936">1936</option>
            <option value="1935">1935</option>
            <option value="1934">1934</option>
            <option value="1933">1933</option>
            <option value="1932">1932</option>
            <option value="1931">1931</option>
            <option value="1930">1930</option>
            <option value="1929">1929</option>
            <option value="1928">1928</option>
            <option value="1927">1927</option>
            <option value="1926">1926</option>
            <option value="1925">1925</option>
            <option value="1924">1924</option>
            <option value="1923">1923</option>
            <option value="1922">1922</option>
            <option value="1921">1921</option>
            <option value="1920">1920</option>
            <option value="1919">1919</option>
            <option value="1918">1918</option>
            <option value="1917">1917</option>
            <option value="1916">1916</option>
            <option value="1915">1915</option>
            <option value="1914">1914</option>
            <option value="1913">1913</option>
            <option value="1912">1912</option>
            <option value="1911">1911</option>
            <option value="1910">1910</option>
            <option value="1909">1909</option>
            <option value="1908">1908</option>
            <option value="1907">1907</option>
            <option value="1906">1906</option>
            <option value="1905">1905</option>
            <option value="1904">1904</option>
            <option value="1903">1903</option>
            <option value="1902">1902</option>
            <option value="1901">1901</option>
            <option value="1900">1900</option>

        </select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-active" style="width:100%;" title="" id="MainContent_ddlScopeYear_chosen"><a class="chosen-single"><span>2021</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><ul class="chosen-results"><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0" style="">--Select--</li><li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="1" style="">2021</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">2020</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3" style="">2019</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4" style="">2018</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5" style="">2017</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="6" style="">2016</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="7" style="">2015</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="8" style="">2014</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="9" style="">2013</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="10" style="">2012</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="11" style="">2011</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="12" style="">2010</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="13" style="">2009</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="14" style="">2008</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="15" style="">2007</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="16" style="">2006</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="17" style="">2005</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="18" style="">2004</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="19" style="">2003</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="20" style="">2002</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="21" style="">2001</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="22" style="">2000</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="23" style="">1999</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="24" style="">1998</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="25" style="">1997</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="26" style="">1996</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="27" style="">1995</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="28" style="">1994</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="29" style="">1993</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="30" style="">1992</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="31" style="">1991</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="32" style="">1990</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="33" style="">1989</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="34" style="">1988</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="35" style="">1987</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="36" style="">1986</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="37" style="">1985</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="38" style="">1984</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="39" style="">1983</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="40" style="">1982</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="41" style="">1981</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="42" style="">1980</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="43" style="">1979</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="44" style="">1978</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="45" style="">1977</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="46" style="">1976</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="47" style="">1975</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="48" style="">1974</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="49" style="">1973</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="50" style="">1972</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="51" style="">1971</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="52" style="">1970</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="53" style="">1969</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="54" style="">1968</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="55" style="">1967</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="56" style="">1966</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="57" style="">1965</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="58" style="">1964</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="59" style="">1963</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="60" style="">1962</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="61" style="">1961</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="62" style="">1960</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="63" style="">1959</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="64" style="">1958</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="65" style="">1957</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="66" style="">1956</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="67" style="">1955</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="68" style="">1954</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="69" style="">1953</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="70" style="">1952</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="71" style="">1951</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="72" style="">1950</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="73" style="">1949</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="74" style="">1948</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="75" style="">1947</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="76" style="">1946</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="77" style="">1945</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="78" style="">1944</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="79" style="">1943</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="80" style="">1942</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="81" style="">1941</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="82" style="">1940</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="83" style="">1939</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="84" style="">1938</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="85" style="">1937</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="86" style="">1936</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="87" style="">1935</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="88" style="">1934</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="89" style="">1933</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="90" style="">1932</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="91" style="">1931</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="92" style="">1930</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="93" style="">1929</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="94" style="">1928</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="95" style="">1927</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="96" style="">1926</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="97" style="">1925</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="98" style="">1924</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="99" style="">1923</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="100" style="">1922</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="101" style="">1921</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="102" style="">1920</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="103" style="">1919</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="104" style="">1918</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="105" style="">1917</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="106" style="">1916</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="107" style="">1915</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="108" style="">1914</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="109" style="">1913</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="110" style="">1912</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="111" style="">1911</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="112" style="">1910</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="113" style="">1909</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="114" style="">1908</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="115" style="">1907</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="116" style="">1906</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="117" style="">1905</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="118" style="">1904</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="119" style="">1903</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="120" style="">1902</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="121" style="">1901</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="122" style="">1900</li></ul></div></div>
                                                <span id="MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator2" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Required</span>
                                                
                                            </div>
```

```html
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlscopegroupp" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$ddlscopegroupp\',\'\')', 0)" id="MainContent_ddlscopegroupp" class="chosen-select select_styled" style="display: none;">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">--Select Product Material--</option>
            <option value="Others">Others</option>

        </select>

<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active" style="width:100%;" title="" id="MainContent_ddlscopegroupp_chosen"><a class="chosen-single"><span>--Select Product Material--</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><ul class="chosen-results"><li class="active-result result-selected highlighted" data-option-array-index="0" style="">--Select Product Material--</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">Others</li></ul></div></div>
```

I am using VBA, code below:

```
    Sub t1()
Dim Driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Set Driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
Driver.Get "https://nablwp.qci.org.in/Test-Lab/ScopeOfAccreditation"
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_btnViewScope").Click

Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_ddlScopeDisci").SendKeys "Electronics"
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_ddlScopeGroup").SendKeys "EMC Test Facility"
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_ddlsbGrp").SendKeys "Radiated Emission Test"
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_txtScopeStand").ScrollIntoView

SetCursorPos 700, 710
SingleClick
SetCursorPos 700, 860
SingleClick

'Below element is another uninteractable one. I am managing it with a mouse click. Luckily, it has only one option in the dropdown, so mouse click works.
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_txtScopeGroup").SendKeys "IT"
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_txtScopeTestPer").SendKeys "Radiated Emission Test"
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_txtScopeStand").SendKeys "CISPR 32:2015/AMD1"
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_txtScopeRangeRem").ScrollIntoView

SetCursorPos 800, 800
SingleClick
SetCursorPos 800, 940
SingleClick
'Below element is another uninteractable one. Mouse click method does not work here, as it has options from year 1900 to 2021!!!
Driver.FindElementByCss("input#MainContent_ddlScopeYear_chosen").SendKeys "2019"

Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_ddlRangeType").SendKeys "Quantitative"
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_txtScopeRangeLL").SendKeys "30"
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_btnllUnit").Click
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_htmext1_ExtenderCOntentEditable").SendKeys "MHz"
Driver.FindElementById("MainContent_btnShowLL").Click
End Sub'
```

I am stepping through the code, and it still does not work, so it does not appear to be time related that can be solved by Wait.

"Display: none" property seems to be creating the issue, need help in solving it in VBA. Thank you.